# How to make GNU/Make stop de-referencing symbolic links to directories

Tags: linux, makefile, build-process, symlink, gnu-make

GNU/Make manual §5.7 states the following:

> 5.7 Recursive Use of make
>
> Recursive use of make means using make as a command in a makefile.
>   This technique is useful when you want separate makefiles for various
>   subsystems that compose a larger system. For example, suppose you have
>   a subdirectory subdir which has its own makefile, and you would like
>   the containing directory's makefile to run make on the subdirectory.
>   You can do it by writing this:
>
> ```
>  subsystem:
>          cd subdir && $(MAKE) or, equivalently, this (see Summary of Options):
>
>  subsystem:
>          $(MAKE) -C subdir
> ```

So, basically it implies that `cd subdir && $(MAKE)` is the same as `$(MAKE) -C subdir`.

However, it turns out that it is not really an equivalent. When using `-C` option, the directory path, if it is a symlink, is always de-referenced, so there is no way to get "logical" (as in `pwd -L`) directory name. Consider the following example. Having the following `Makefile` in `/tmp/b` directory, which is a symlink to `/tmp/a/` directory:

```
foo:
    @echo PWDL=$(shell pwd -L)
    @echo PWDP=$(shell pwd -P)
    @echo CURDIR=$(CURDIR)
```

Now, let's invoke `make` differently:

```
$ pwd
/tmp
$ (cd b && make foo)
PWDL=/tmp/b
PWDP=/tmp/a
CURDIR=/tmp/a
$ make -C b foo
make: Entering directory `/tmp/a'
PWDL=/tmp/a
PWDP=/tmp/a
CURDIR=/tmp/a
make: Leaving directory `/tmp/a'
$ make --directory=b foo
make: Entering directory `/tmp/a'
PWDL=/tmp/a
PWDP=/tmp/a
CURDIR=/tmp/a
make: Leaving directory `/tmp/a'
$
```

As you can see, `pwd -P` and `$(CURDIR)` are always showing de-referenced symbolic link. But `pwd -L` works only when changing directory before running `make`, which proves that `-C` option to GNU/Make always makes it de-reference the directory path, for no good reason. I was trying to find any explanation for this behavior in the documentation but couldn't. Neither I can come up with a workaround for this problem without changing directory using `cd` before running  `make` (or w/o very bad hooks trough `LD_PRELOAD`).

The question is - did anyone else run into this problem before, have an explanation or a workaround? Thanks!

**UPDATE:**

Trying to get to the bottom of it, I have downloaded source code for `make` and did not find any special processing of directories, only calls to `chdir`. So I wrote a little program to conduct an experiment, and here is what I found.

When you are in a symlinked directory (`/tmp/b`) and trying to change directory to the same, the operation has no effect and current working directory continues to point to the symbolic link.

When you call `chdir ()` and specify either full or relative path, it de-references it before changing directory. Here is a prove:

```
$ cat cd.cpp 
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main ()
{
    chdir ("/tmp/b/");
    printf ("Current dir: %s\n",
        get_current_dir_name ()); /* Forgive my memory leak. */
}

$ gcc -o test ./cd.cpp 
$ pwd
/tmp/b
$ ./test 
Current dir: /tmp/b
$ cd ../
$ ./b/test 
Current dir: /tmp/a
$ cd /
$ /tmp/b/test 
Current dir: /tmp/a
$
```

So it seems like either `libc` or Linux is playing tricks on me that I didn't really care about before. And on top of that, bash`s`cd` is working somehow different.

Strangely enough, [Linux `chdir ()` man page](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/chdir.2.html) doesn't mention anything about it, but there is a note on it in Borland Builder (!sic) documentation, [here](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v5r3/index.jsp?topic=/apis/chdir.htm). So I wonder what `bash` does in this regard.

Comment: This is the behavior I would expect from make, actually.  The "logical" directory is purely an invention by the shell, which does extra work to maintain the illusion.

Comment: @ephemient: I thought it is doing something like that, but strangely, when doing `cd` and invoking a process that calls `getcwd ()`, `getcwd ()` returns a path to symlink, and not the real directory. I have tried to call `chdir ()` with full path to symlink and cannot get the same effect. I am wondering what exactly is going on.

Comment: `bash` caches the working directory in `$PWD`.  `cd` in shell updates `$PWD`.  `pwd` in shell returns `$PWD` if it matches the real working directory.  When you use `cd && $(MAKE)`, the variable is set for the recursive invocation; when you use `$(MAKE) -C`, it's not, and `pwd` falls back to the uncached physical path.

Comment: @ephemient: And the whole thing works until.... I'm going to sketch up a little answer about this thing. It's a mess. Huh.

Comment: BTW: Glibc's `get_current_dir_name` does check `getenv("PWD")`.  `make` and `bash` just use `getcwd`, however.  And obviously, this is all implementation-specific detail.

Comment: @ephemient: You are right. There is no way to actually `chdir ()` to a symlink, if only there was `chdir ()` accepting inode... Anyways, I will keep far far away from "symlinks as cwd" concept in the future. Thanks for your help figuring this out!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

With [ephemient](https://stackoverflow.com/users/20713/ephemient)'s help I was able to figure this one out. So there are few things that are going on:

1. Linux does not support having current working directory set to a symlink. `chdir ()` always sets it to the real directory.
2. There is a variable called `PWD` that represents a current working directory, by convention.
3. Some of the function/system calls honor `PWD` variable and some do not.
4. Bash maintains a "fake" path built using symbolic names and sets `PWD` variable accordingly.

It explains `gmake` behavior. When `gmake` is invoked by `sh`, `PWD` is updated before `gmake` process is executed. Thus, `PWD` is set to "symbolic" path and functions honoring it continue to work fine. Otherwise, `gmake` calls `chdir ()`, which changes working directory and sets `PWD` without sh's tricks. Thus, all functions including those honoring `PWD` start to return "real" path.

All in all, I'd say that depending on symbolic path name is a bad idea and things can easily fall apart. For example, because `getcwd ()` system call doesn't care about `PWD`. Invoking `cd` before running `make` works as a short term solution though.