# Expand a relative path but not follow any symlink in the path in Python

Tags: python, system

This is a subtle question, I know, but I hope you can bear with me for a moment.

Suppose `/tmp/dir` is a symlink to `/home/user/some/dir`.  Suppose also that your current working directory is `/tmp/dir`.

Even expanding something like `.` does not seem to be possible, as `os.getcwd()` returns `/home/user/some/dir` instead of `/tmp/dir`, which is what `pwd` command returns.  Relative dir can also be `../dir/../dir/subdir`, `.././././dir/foo`, etc.

So my question: Is there any reliable function that does path expansion of a relative path but does not follow the symlink that may exist in the relative path.  In case of `../dir/../dir/subdir`, for example, I would like to get `/tmp/dir/subdir` and NOT `/home/user/some/dir/subdir`.

Just to avoid getting something I do not want, the answer is NOT `os.path.abspath`, `os.path.realpath`, `os.path.expanduser`, or `os.path.relpath`.

Comment: are you sure, you don't get what you want via  `os.path.realpath(os.path.expanduser('../dir/../dir/subdir'))`

Comment: @podshumok You will then get `/home/user/some/dir/subdir`, which is specifically what I do not want to get.

Comment: Strange. If I set up these exact conditions, `os.getcwd()` actually returns `/home/user/some/dir` even if I'm in `/tmp/dir`. Not sure if it matters, but might be worth specifying which Python version you're using in case it changed.

Comment: Looks like it's actually the the OS (Ubuntu in this case) doing this. Using `bash`, if I `cd /tmp/dir`, the built-in `pwd` returns `/tmp/dir`, but running `/bin/pwd` returns `/home/user/some/dir`, which matches `/proc/self/cwd`.

Comment: @Aya Actually, yes. `os.getcwd()` does follow symlink in this case for me too (Ubuntu and Mac X 10.6). My assumption was that os.getcwd returns exactly what `pwd` command does - so my bad. Editing the original post to avoid further confusion.

Comment: @OTZ I get the same behavior in a C program which calls [`chdir(2)`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/chdir), so it looks as if it's illegal for a process to have a working directory which is a symlink. I was just about to read the kernel source code to confirm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems as if [you're not the first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8390502/how-to-make-gnu-make-stop-de-referencing-symbolic-links-to-directories) to notice this odd behavior of [`chdir(2)`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/chdir).

There's nothing about it in the Linux manpage, but [a similar page](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v5r3/index.jsp?topic=/apis/chdir.htm) says...

> `int chdir(const char *path);`
>
> [...]
>
> The **chdir()** function makes the directory named by *path* the new
>   current directory. If the last component of *path* is a symbolic link,
>   **chdir()** resolves the contents of the symbolic link. If the **chdir()** function fails, the current directory is unchanged.

...although with no explanation as to why it resolves the symbolic link.

So, you can't technically have a current working directory of `/tmp/dir`, even if your shell claims otherwise.

However, you can exploit the fact that the shell's built-in `cd` command sets the environment variable `PWD` to the value you entered, so you can do this...

```
$ cd /tmp/dir
$ python
>>> import os
>>> os.getcwd()
'/home/user/some/dir'
>>> os.environ['PWD']
'/tmp/dir'
>>> os.path.normpath(os.path.join(os.environ['PWD'], '../dir/../dir/subdir'))
'/tmp/dir/subdir'
```

...although it may fail in cases when the process wasn't started from a shell.

Comment: Thanks so much for your thorough investigation of this issue.  I did try `os.environ['PWD']`, but did not go so far like you did. `os.path.normpath` normalization does work much better and indeed may very well be the best option in this case. Didn't have time looking into source code of `pwd` command; and I suspect what it does inside may not be fully implementable. Thanks again, Aya!

Comment: @OTZ The `pwd` shell built-in pretty much just does `echo $PWD`, whereas `/bin/pwd` pretty much just does `print os.getcwd()`.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure that's what you're looking for, but... you can write a function that generate the "logical" full path from the relative path and current working directory then check that the generated path really exists on the system. That function could look like:

```
import os

def absolute_path(path):
    wd = os.getcwd()
    full = os.path.join(wd, path)

    parts = full.split(os.sep)
    kept = []
    skip = 0
    for part in reversed(parts):
        if part == '..':
            skip += 1
        elif skip == 0:
            kept.insert(0, part)
        else:
            skip -= 1
    return os.sep + os.path.join(*kept)
```